# Error undefined variable en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, los datos se actualizan pero me da el error de "Undefined variable $output in eliminarProducto.php on line 29". El código en PHP es el siguiente:

´´´<?php
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";

```
if($codigo){
    include 'conexion.php';
    if($conexion){
        
        $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=?";
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $outPut="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            }else{
                $outPut="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }    
        }else{
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $output="No hay conexion";
    }
}else{
    $output="Codigo vacio o no valido";
}

echo $output;
```

?>

Comment: Debes respetar mayúsculas y minúsculas. Tienes `$outPut="Filas actualizadas: "...;` y esa `P` hace que la variable `$output` no esté definida.

Comment: ya cambié outPut por output y ya no da el error

Answer (score 2):

PHP es case sensitive es decir imprtan mucho las mayusculas y minusculas, en un lado tienes la variable **$output** y en otro lado **$outPut** y al final de todo el codigo devuelves **$output** y esta variable solo existe en algunas partes del codigo.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta, cambie outPut por output, y ya no tengo ese error por suerte